# Custom validation for from and to date in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, date-format, customvalidator, custom-validators

i am developing web application in vb.net, using Custom validation how to validate the from date and To date..

i need to validate the Date in the asp:textbox should be "dd/mm/yyyy" format and i have two date like from date and Todate. So the Todate should not be less then start date, Can anyone please help me,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is VB.Net Way to do it. You can modify it to fit asp.net

```
Dim date1 As DateTime = "01/01/2000"
Dim date2 As DateTime = "07/09/2012"

Dim myDate As DateTime = InputBox("Date?")

If myDate >= date1 AndAlso myDate <= date2 Then
  MsgBox("Between")
Else
  MsgBox("Not between")
End If
```